# Copy all files from one directory to another

Tags: vbscript, scripting

I want to copy all file from folder1 to folder2 if folder 2 is empty.

For example: `file1.txt`, `file2.pdf` etc are present in `folder1`, and there are two folders: `folder1` and `folder2`, and `folder1` should send all files to `folder2` if its empty.

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso 

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

fso.CopyFile "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\from\", "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\to"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w.aspx):

> **`object.CopyFile ( source, destination[, overwrite] )`**
>
> **Arguments**
>
> [...]
>
> `source`
>   Required. Character string file specification, which can include wildcard characters, for one or more files to be copied.
>
> `destination`
>   Required. Character string destination where the file or files from source are to be copied. Wildcard characters are not allowed.
>
> [...]
>
> **Remarks**
>
> Wildcard characters can only be used in the last path component of the source argument. For example, you can use:
>   [...]
>   If source contains wildcard characters or destination ends with a path separator (\), it is assumed that destination is an existing folder in which to copy matching files. Otherwise, destination is assumed to be the name of a file to create.

Change

```
fso.CopyFile "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\from\", "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\to"
```

to

```
fso.CopyFile "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\from\*.*", "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\to\"
```

and the code will copy everything from the source folder to the destination folder.

However, since you only want to copy when the destination folder is empty, you'll want to check that first:

```
If fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\abc\Desktop\to").Files.Count = 0 Then
    fso.CopyFile "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\from\*.*", "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\to\"
End If
```

If the destination must also not contain any folders you'll need to check for the existence of subfolders as well.